# In what order does the Akatsuki capture the Tailed Beasts?

Tags: naruto

In Episode 83, two or three episodes after Hidan and Kakuzu capture the Two Tails, Nagato says that only 4 beasts are left. But in the anime, only two beasts were shown to be captured (Shukaku and the Two Tails). So 7 beasts remain. Are there any movies in between or did I miss any episode?

Comment: IIRC there is an episode that shows the recap of them all being caught.

Comment: They just didn't show it I guess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Timeline as figured by me**
1.Kokuo(Han) was captured BEFORE shipuuden start

> Kokuō, after living in an unspecified forest, eventually fell into the possession of Iwagakure and was sealed into Han, but was captured and extracted by Akatsuki.

2.Gyuki was captured BEFORE shipuuden starts

> In the anime, during a joint Chūnin Exams between Konohagakure and Sunagakure, Fū attempted to stop the Suna-nin Hōichi from extracting Shukaku from its host Gaara. Her failed attempt caused her to draw the attention of Hōichi, who also began extracting Chōmei from Fū.[6] Ultimately, the extraction was stopped by the intervention of Neji Hyūga, who used his Gentle Fist to block the chakra points from which Chōmei was being extracted, thereby repelling the chains.[7] Fū was later captured by Akatsuki members Kakuzu and Hidan, leading to Chōmei being extracted from its jinchūriki and sealed within the Demonic Statue of the Outer Path.[8]

Shipuuden Starts
3.Deidara (and Sasori) capture Shukaku (Gaara) - Naruto Returns

> During Gaara's time as the Fifth Kazekage, Deidara and Sasori from the Akatsuki were assigned to capture Shukaku.

4.Hidan and Kakuzu capture Matatabi (Yugito) - Akatsuki Suppression; Asuma Dies

> Soon after her introduction, Yugito was captured by two Akatsuki members, Hidan and Kakuzu.

5.Tobi and Deidara capture Isubo the three tails - Naruto starts his wind training

> In the manga, Tobi and Deidara confronted the beast around the same time Naruto Uzumaki had begun his Wind Release training, to which it responded by beginning to chase Tobi. With the Three-Tails distracted, Deidara moulded an explosive clay fish in an attempt to capture it.
>  This was a filler arc in the Anime, wherein Leaf tried to capture the beast and failed

6.Kisame capture Son Goku(Roshi) - Itachi is pursued; Sasuke Vs Deidara

> After an unseen and difficult battle with Kisame Hoshigaki, Rōshi was defeated and captured by the Akatsuki member

7.Anime only: Saiken (Utakata) is captured by Pain

> In the anime, in an attempt to stop the Fury technique from causing untold destruction, Utakata went into his full Six-Tails form to shield the blast. Later, Utakata was confronted and captured by Nagato's Six Paths of Pain. Afterwards, Saiken was extracted from Utakata's body, being sealed into the Demonic Statue of the Outer Path, thus killing the jinchūriki in the process.
>
> So 2 beasts were captured before anime started. The 4th Mizukage's beast was roaming alone for some reason and Utakata's beast I am not sure about. In Anime, its shown after Roshi, need a rewatch to confirm. As I remember Utakata was captured while Sasuke fought Itachi and Jiraiya, Pain.

8.9.Gyuki and Kurama capture failed by Kisame and Pain.

EDIT: Added relevant quotes for all the beasts from the wikia (Source)

Comment: Wasn't in Shippuden when Fu participate the Chunin Exam?

Comment: That was a flashback arc shown in shipuuden. But the chuunin exams take place before the start of Shipuuden i.e. Naruto's Homecoming

Answer (score 1):

***Spoilers***

In Naruto when a tailed beast is sealed in the Gedo Mazo (or Demonic Statue of the Outer Path) a pupil shows up in one of the eyes. We can use this to determine the order that the tailed beasts were sealed in.

In the beginning of Naruto Shippuden 2 tailed beasts were already sealed. (Manga ch.256 p.16) These tailed beasts are never confirmed but I believe they are Kokuo (5 tails) and Chomei (7 tails). In the anime Chomei was captured during the joint Chūnin Exams between Konohagakure and Sunagakure. This happened before Shippuden started. (Hopes Entrusted to the Future, episode 413 of Naruto: Shippūden) As for Kokuo I have evidence of when every other tailed beast was sealed so he has to have been sealed before Shippuden.

The next one sealed was Shukaku (1 tail). The picture is low quality but you can see for sure in Manga ch.261 p.17. If you compare this picture with Manga ch.256 p.16, you can see that there was two beasts sealed before Shukaku and 3 beasts sealed after.

The next time we see the Gedo Mazo is in chapter 329, when it has 4 tailed beasts sealed inside of it. This is where it gets confusing because Saiken (6 tails) is the only tailed beast that could have been sealed in this gap. However, the wiki says he doesn't get sealed until after Sasuke fights Itachi. Saiken gets captured during the Six-Tails Unleashed arc, which covers episodes 144 to 151. I don't think there is anything in these episodes that say this has to occur after Sasuke fights Itachi, so we can say this happens after Garra was captured and before Asuma dies.

The next tailed beast is sealed right after Asuma dies. This is Isobu (3 tails). You can see this in chapter 331 p.13.

The next tailed beast is Matatabi (2 tails). Most people think she was sealed before the 3 tails because she was captured before the three tails. I don't know why Akatsuki waited to seal her. Maybe because the three tails didn't have a jinchuriki so they decided to seal it first. Anyway you can see this in ch.332 p.6.

The last tailed beast Akatsuki seals is Son Goku (4 tails). He is sealed in ch.354 p.11. The picture isn't great here but if you look at ch.332 p.6 when Matatabi was sealed you can see there is only 3 tailed beasts left.

Gyuki (8 tails) and Kurama (9 tails) are not sealed in the Gedo Mazo until the fourth Great Shinobi World War. At which point Akatsuki is pretty much no longer around. I do want to point out that some of Gyuki was sealed in the Gedo Mazo in ch.419 p.11.

This is the order that the tailed beasts were sealed in:
*I added not confirmed for the ones that the manga does not explicitly state.

1. Kokuo (5 tails) - not confirmed
2. Chomei (7 tails) - not confirmed
3. Shukaku (1 tail)
4. Saiken (6 tails) - not confirmed
5. Isobu (3 tails)
6. Matatabi (2 tails)
7. Son Goku (4 tails)
8. Gyuki (8 tails) - kinda

In the war Madara seals them all in the correct order. Including Kurama.

The order that the tailed beasts were captured is similar to the order they were sealed:

1. Kokuo (5 tails) - not confirmed
2. Chomei (7 tails) - not confirmed
3. Shukaku (1 tail)
4. Saiken (6 tails) - not confirmed
5. Matatabi (2 tails)
6. Isobu (3 tails)
7. Son Goku (4 tails)
8. Gyuki (8 tails) - kinda

If you are curious who captured each tailed beast:

1. Kokuo (5 tails) - unknown
2. Chomei (7 tails) - Kakuzu and Hidan
3. Shukaku (1 tail) - Deidara
4. Saiken (6 tails) - Pain
5. Matatabi (2 tails) - Kakuzu and Hidan
6. Isobu (3 tails) - Deidara and kinda Tobi
7. Son Goku (4 tails) - Itachi and Kisame
8. Gyuki (8 tails) - Team Taka - Sasuke, Suigetsu, Karin, and Jugo

Comment: I know this question is 2 and a half years old, but I couldn't find anyone who posted the correct order anywhere online.

Answer (score 0):

1 tailed deidara
2 tails hidan
3 tailed without host because tobi manipulated yagura and deidara capture 3 tails without host
4 tails kisame
5 tailed never shown in anime so manga only, there a chance it must be deidara.
6 tail 6 paths of pain
7 tail kakazu and hidan when the chunin exam was finished
8 tail was sasuke but failed
9 tail six path of pain and nagato but later on died.